# Using a promise with Fetch API response still has my data returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I am building a simple web app that allows users to search the stats of a player in a video game.

Here is my code

```js
let player = [];
let proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
    let url =  proxy + "https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hess"

function getPlayer() {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
getPlayer().then((playerData) => {
  console.log(playerData);
  playerData.push(player);
  console.log(player);
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to console.log the response and push the response to an array `player` so I can later use the fecthed data in the `player` array to perform some other actions on.

Why is it returning undefined? Why won't my response get pushed into the `player` array?

Comment: You want to use `player.push(playerData)`, and you also want to either remove your `.then()` which the console log in `getPlayer()` or make your callback in the last `.then()` in `getPlayer()` return `data` (so it is available in the next returned promise). Keep in mind that the data in `player` will only be available once you've pushed to it, which occurs asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let player = [];
let proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
let url = proxy + "https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hess"

function getPlayer() {
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return data;
        });
}
getPlayer().then((playerData) => {
    console.log(playerData);
    player.push(playerData);
    console.log(player);
});
```

You need to make sure you are returning a value at each step of your .then(). And your .push is the wrong way round

Comment: Hmm okay I see, so basically I was correct except for the fact that I need to use ‘return’. However, I actually learned of this solution through this link https://theprogrammershangout.com/resources/javascript/promises/intro.md/, and as you can see, the example does not use return. In fact, I have used an fetch before and was doing something similar, and never needed the return. Just confused on why return is needed if the whole point of using a promise was to “wait”

Comment: Writing .then((data) => {
return data
}
Is the same as writing .then((data) => data). That's probably what caused the confusion

Answer (score 1):

as i see it you probably switch by mistake here the array and the data
in the code below you accidentally push the array to the playerData and not the opisite

```
playerData.push(player);
```

you shoud do this
player.push(playerData)

and I think you should also remove the second then if you console log it as the people says here to get data but i think you can also use the first then and if  you want the second one just do this:

```
    function getPlayer() {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => data);
}
```